# Selecting only non null fields from the filter rows django

Tags: sql, django, database, orm

I have this query which are getting the required rows which i want but the problem is most fields/columns have null values I just want to get only those fields from these rows which have non null values

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(email__exact=email)
```

Here, is my model

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=40, null=True)
    source = models.CharField(default='unknown', max_length=150, null=True)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    before_at = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    ipaddress = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        if self.email != None:
            return self.email
        elif self.username != None:
            return self.username
```

Comment: Why do you make all fields `null=True` in the first place? Often it is rare to have NULLable fields.

Comment: Honestly, you have bigger problems if this is your custom user model (email and username are not unique, __str__ will return empty strings...). A lot of these fields have nothing to do with authentication and should be moved to a user profile.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, You can use this:

```
  for q in queryset:
    if q.email == None or q.username == None:
      queryset = queryset.exclude(email=q.email)
```

I hope that this would solve your problem.

Comment: The solution is very specific and will fail in case there are null columns other than `email` and `username`. Better solution will be to filer out the nullable columns while fetching the queryset itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a list of NULLable fields with:

```
nullable_fields = [f.name for f in User._meta.get_fields() if f.null]
```

With these fields, we can make a filter:

```
nonnullq = Q(
    *[f('{field}__isnull', False) for field in nullable_fields],
    _connector=Q.AND
)
```

We can use this filter to exclude all records where one if the fields is NULL:

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(nonnullq, email=email)
```

That being said, it is rather odd that nearly all fields are NULLable. Often only a small amount is NULLable, since it often makes models more complicated.